# C# How can write a client and server in win app to transfer http

Tags: c#, http, windows-services, client-server

I am interesting to write a C# Client Server application and there are my issues:

1-the client App must be a WinServer

2-the client side, store some files, zipped them and send by http (no TCP or UDP or Socket) to the Server

3-the client side must check the server if the server was offline must be store zip files in some place of local machine and by schedule check the server to start transfer them.

4-the server send some command to client (or client check the server for commands) and need a command execution in client side

5-the client need to check server for some parameters or replace them by default(if server was offline or did not suggest any parameter)

I need some idea about the implementation of this, Does any one have any Idea about it?

Comment: Your question is far too broad for anyone to answer and, I suspect from some of the things you wrote, you have quite a bit of studying to do before you are able to ask the right questions I'm afraid. At least try breaking it down a bit and telling us what you've tried already.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with thinking about WCF service in your server application, then have the clients communicate with the server. If you're asking for the all the specifics of how to go about this challenge, I suggest you start with researching WCF and seeing if you can get a basic client/server up and running first, then ask about specific issues.

Then, progress to a WCF host in the client, so the server can communicate back.

Then you can tackle such things as file transfers, offline availability etc.

I've not done this, but this is how I would figure out how to start tackling this.